Azure pipeline not running in my environment
I'm getting the below prompt if I am trying to run a new pipeline:


You can follow the steps shared in my answer to try to check the "Pipeline permissions" and "User permissions" in the agent pool. @Anjumaara

Based on the error message, your pipeline does not have the permissions to use the agent pool 'Anjum'.
You need to contact the user who is the Project Collection Administrators (PCA) of the organization and ask the PCA user to check with the following things:

Go to "Organization Settings" > "Agent pools", ensure you can see the pool 'Anjum' is existing. If cannot see the pool, the pool indeed does not exist in the organization. Consider creating a new pool with the name 'Anjum' and add some agents into this new pool for use.

On "Organization Settings" > "Agent pools", open the agent pool 'Anjum'. On 'Settings' tab, enable the option "Auto-provision this agent pool in new projects".


In the project where the pipeline is in, go to "Project Settings" > "Agent pools". Open the pool 'Anjum' and go to the 'Security' tab to configure the access.

At the "Pipeline permissions" section, can either click "Open access" to let all the pipeline can access this pool or click "Add pipeline" (+) to give particular pipeline with the access.



At the "User permissions" section, can assign the particular user with the 'User' role permission so that the user can use this pool in his pipelines. Also can assign the role permission to particular group.






